# Google Map itinerary from geoJSON file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson, google-directions-api

I'd like to draw an itinerary between 2 markers which are defined in this geoJSON file:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features":

 [

    { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-73.563032, 45.495403]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    },

    { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-73.549762, 45.559673]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    }
]

}
```

The two markers are displayed well on the map.

Now I want to create an itinerary (car), between those two points.

I have this javascript function, which allows me to draw an itinerary from a form filled by the user:

```
function calculate() {

origin      =   document.getElementById('origin').value;
destination =   document.getElementById('destination').value;


var request = {
origin: origin,
destination: destination,


travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     }
   });
  }
```

And now, I would like to replace the "origin" and "destination", by the 2 points defined in my geoJSON file, in order to create an itinerary between those two points.

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: How are you displaying the GeoJSON data?  The general answer to your question would be to parse the GeoJSON for the coordinates, make them into google.maps.LatLng objects, and pass those into the directions service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, use the Google Maps Data Layer to display your GeoJSON.  The use it to retrieve the coordinates and get directions between them.  The below code assumes 2 points (and uses your example with 2 points):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgg69/1/)

```
function calculate() {
    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,


        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

// global variables
var origin = null;
var destination = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
    // Create a simple map.
    features = [];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {
            lat: -28,
            lng: 137.883
        }
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowidow.close();
    });
    // process the loaded GeoJSON data.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map.data, 'addfeature', function (e) {
        if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
            map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
            // set the origin to the first point
            if (!origin) origin = e.feature.getGeometry().get();
            // set the destination to the second point
            else if (!destination) {
                destination = e.feature.getGeometry().get();
                // calculate the directions once both origin and destination are set 
                calculate();
            }
        }
    });
    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```